# The npc will move to the first or second point, then stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

The enemy will pick 1 or 2 positions, and then stop moving. If I get close enough, it will change to the chase state and follow me. So I do not know what causes them to freeze.

This holds the state machine, I intend to have more states and interactions, but I wanted to test the basic functionality, and it is broken.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BaseAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private enum State
    {
        Roaming,
        ChaseTarget,
    }
    private PathfindAI pathMovement;
    private Vector3 startingPosition;
    public Vector3 roamPosition;
   
    public PlayerScript player;

    public Vector3 randomDirection;
   [SerializeField] private State state;
    public Vector3 playerPos;

    private void Awake()
    {
      //  pathMovement = GetComponent<PathfindAI>();
        pathMovement = FindObjectOfType<PathfindAI>();
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerScript>();
        state = State.Roaming;
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        startingPosition = transform.position;
        roamPosition = GetRoamingPos();
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        playerPos = player.PlayerPos();
        

        switch (state)
        {
            default:
            case State.Roaming:

                pathMovement.MoveTo(roamPosition);
                float reachedPos = 10f;
             if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, roamPosition) < reachedPos)
              {
                //reached destination
                roamPosition = GetRoamingPos();
                    
                }
                FindTarget();
                break;

            case State.ChaseTarget:

                pathMovement.MoveTo(playerPos);
                float attackRange = 10f;
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) < attackRange)
                {
                    //target within striking distance

                }
                break;
        }
    }
    private Vector3 GetRoamingPos()
    {
        randomDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f), transform.position.z).normalized;

        return startingPosition + randomDirection * Random.Range(10f, 70f);
    }

    private void FindTarget()
    {
        float targetRange = 50f;
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) < targetRange)
        {
            state = State.ChaseTarget;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows them to move on the path from the pathfinding script. It uses A-star and I used a few tutorials to write it, mostly from CodeMonkey's youtube channel.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PathfindAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed = 5f;
    private int currentPathIndex;
    private List<Vector3> pathVectorList;
   

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
     
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        Debug.Log(currentPathIndex);
    }

    public Vector3 GetPosition()
    {
        return transform.position;
    }

    public void MoveTo(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        SetTargetPos(targetPosition);
        HandleMove();
    }

    private void SetTargetPos(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        currentPathIndex = 0;
        pathVectorList = AStar.Instance.FindPathVector3(GetPosition(), targetPosition);

        if (pathVectorList != null && pathVectorList.Count > 1)
        {
            pathVectorList.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    public void HandleMove()
    {
        if (pathVectorList != null)
        {
            Vector3 targetPosition = pathVectorList[currentPathIndex];
           if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) > 5f)
            {
                Vector3 moveDir = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized;

                float distanceBefore = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition);

                transform.position = transform.position + moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            else
            {
                currentPathIndex++;
                if(currentPathIndex >= pathVectorList.Count)
                {
                    StopMoving();
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void StopMoving()
    {   
        pathVectorList = null;
    }
}
```

I suspect the error involves the HandleMove function. When I change where and how I call it; I can get it to break completely. It may be me setting the pathVectorList to null; however, it should be set back to a valid value on the next update when GetRoamingPos is called again within the roaming state.

when I go into the inspector and manually move the npc, it will find its way back to the position it chose. And if I move the player close enough it will chase me.

This is my A-Star Implementation

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AStar 
{
    private const int MOVE_STRAIGHT_COST = 10;
    private const int MOVE_ANGLE_COST = 14;

    public static AStar Instance { get; private set; }

    private PathingGrid<PathNode> grid;
    private List<PathNode> openList;
    private List<PathNode> closedList;

    public AStar(int width, int height)
    {
        Instance = this;
       grid = new PathingGrid<PathNode>(width, height, 10f, Vector3.zero, (PathingGrid<PathNode> g, int x, int y) => new PathNode(g, x, y));
    }

    public PathingGrid<PathNode> GetGrid()
    {
        return grid;
    }

    public List<PathNode> FindPath(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {
        PathNode startNode = grid.GetGridObject(startX, startY);
        PathNode endNode = grid.GetGridObject(endX, endY);

        openList = new List<PathNode> { startNode };
        closedList = new List<PathNode>();

        for (int x = 0; x<grid.GetWidth(); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y<grid.GetHeight(); y++)
            {
                PathNode pathNode = grid.GetGridObject(x, y);
                pathNode.gCost = int.MaxValue;
                pathNode.CalcFCost();
                pathNode.cameFromNode = null;
            }
        }

        startNode.gCost = 0;
        startNode.hCost = CalculateDistanceCost(startNode, endNode);
        startNode.CalcFCost();

        while (openList.Count > 0)
        {
            PathNode currentNode = GetLowestFCost(openList);

            if (currentNode == endNode)
            {
                //reached final node
                return CalculatedPath(endNode);
            }

            openList.Remove(currentNode);
            closedList.Add(currentNode);

            foreach (PathNode neighbourNode in GetNeighboursList(currentNode))
            {
                if (closedList.Contains(neighbourNode))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!neighbourNode.isWalkable)
                {
                    closedList.Add(neighbourNode);
                    continue;
                }

                int tentativeGCost = currentNode.gCost + CalculateDistanceCost(currentNode, neighbourNode);
                if (tentativeGCost < neighbourNode.gCost)
                {
                    neighbourNode.cameFromNode = currentNode;
                    neighbourNode.gCost = tentativeGCost;
                    neighbourNode.hCost = CalculateDistanceCost(neighbourNode, endNode);
                    neighbourNode.CalcFCost();

                    if(!openList.Contains(neighbourNode))
                    {
                        openList.Add(neighbourNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //out of nodes on openList
        return null;
    }

    private List<PathNode> GetNeighboursList(PathNode currentNode)
    {
        List<PathNode> neighbourList = new List<PathNode>();

        if (currentNode.x - 1 >= 0)
        {
            //left
            neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x - 1, currentNode.y));
            //left down
            if (currentNode.y - 1 >= 0) 
            
                neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x - 1, currentNode.y - 1)); 
            
            //left up
            if (currentNode.y + 1 < grid.GetHeight()) 
            
                neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x - 1, currentNode.y + 1)); 
            
        }

        if (currentNode.x + 1 < grid.GetWidth())
        {
            //right
            neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x + 1, currentNode.y));
            //right down
            if (currentNode.y - 1 >= 0) 
            
                neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x + 1, currentNode.y - 1)); 
            
            //right up
            if (currentNode.y + 1 < grid.GetHeight()) 
             
                neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x + 1, currentNode.y + 1));
            
        }
        //down
        if (currentNode.y - 1 >= 0)
         
            neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x, currentNode.y - 1));
        
        //up
        if (currentNode.y + 1 < grid.GetHeight()) 
        
            neighbourList.Add(GetNode(currentNode.x, currentNode.y + 1)); 
        

        return neighbourList;
    }

    public PathNode GetNode(int x, int y)
    {
        return grid.GetGridObject(x, y);
    }

    public List<Vector3> FindPathVector3(Vector3 startWorldPosition, Vector3 endWorldPosition)
    {
        grid.GetXY(startWorldPosition, out int startX, out int startY);
        grid.GetXY(endWorldPosition, out int endX, out int endY);

        List<PathNode> path = FindPath(startX, startY, endX, endY);

        if (path == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        else
        {
            List<Vector3> vectorPath = new List<Vector3>();
            
            foreach(PathNode pathNode in path)
            {
                vectorPath.Add(new Vector3(pathNode.x, pathNode.y) * grid.GetCellSize() + Vector3.one * grid.GetCellSize() * .5f);
            }
            return vectorPath;

        }
    }

    private List<PathNode> CalculatedPath(PathNode endNode)
    {
        List<PathNode> path = new List<PathNode>();
        path.Add(endNode);
        PathNode currentNode = endNode;
        while (currentNode.cameFromNode != null)
        {
            path.Add(currentNode.cameFromNode);
            currentNode = currentNode.cameFromNode;
        }
        path.Reverse();
        return path;
    }

    private int CalculateDistanceCost(PathNode a,PathNode b)
    {
        int xDistance = Mathf.Abs(a.x - b.x);
        int yDistance = Mathf.Abs(a.y - b.y);
        int remaining = Mathf.Abs(xDistance - yDistance);
        return MOVE_ANGLE_COST * Mathf.Min(xDistance, yDistance) + MOVE_STRAIGHT_COST * remaining;
    }

    private PathNode GetLowestFCost(List<PathNode> pathNodeList)
    {
        PathNode lowestFCostNode = pathNodeList[0];

        for ( int i = 1; i < pathNodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (pathNodeList[i].fCost < lowestFCostNode.fCost)
            {
                lowestFCostNode = pathNodeList[i];
            }
        }

        return lowestFCostNode;
    }

}
```

One interesting point to note is that whenever my random point is chosen outside of the grid I have made, the error is not thrown where I would expect. Instead they claim that in my calculateDistance Cost"int xDistance = Mathf.Abs(a.x - b.x);" is not Finding an instanced Pathnode. Which makes sense because there wouldn't be one there. However, I would not expect that to be where the first error occurs with an out of bounds endpoint.

Comment: In general: Please don't delete and repost the same question.

Comment: Could you include your `FindPathVector3` implementation?

Comment: Your `StopMoving` seems a little bit redundant if as you say in the next frame it is updated and set to a new list anyway, also the `currentPathIndex` seems redundant since you remove the first item and then always use `0` .. the increasing of the index never really matters as in the next frame it is already reset to `0` anyway

Comment: Habe you tried [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) line by line in the moment where your object stopped? This should spread some light on what exactly is going on in that case

Comment: @derHugo I only did so because no one responded. I have sent debug.logs in nearly every line and basically all I find is that it only uses the GetRoamPos once or twice before the index goes from 0 -> 1 and then it freezes. The intention is to have stopmoving set it to null so it stops for a moment, to look like it is "Thinking" it doesn't work as intended. but commenting it out does not change the result at all. I can add my FindPathVector in a moment. I notice it also doesn't call GetRoamPos twice every time it runs. sometimes once, never more than twice.

Comment: I added my A-Star Script which has my FindPathVector3, just after checking for neighbours.

Comment: @derHugo I know tone is hard to portray over text, I appreciate you helping me! I have been stuck on this for days!! <3